# How soon can I reapply for a short-stay Schengen Visa?

Tags: schengen

I was granted a Schengen visa from France which has a validity until 19/10/19. I have an upcoming trip to the Czech republic on Nov 1-Nov. 7. When can I apply for another visa? Can I apply for it as early as the 1st week of October or do I have to wait for the expiration on the 19th of October?

Answer (score 1):

If your visa is a multiple-entry visa with a validity period of at least six months, you can apply for a new visa up to six months before it expires (any time after 19 April 2019).  Otherwise, you must apply within three months of your travel date (any time after 1 August 2019).  This is specified in the [Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412) at Article 9(1):

> CHAPTER II
>
> Application
>
> Article 9
>
> Practical modalities for lodging an application
>
> 1.  Applications shall be lodged no more than three months before the start of the intended visit. Holders of a multiple-entry visa may lodge the application before the expiry of the visa valid for a period of at least six months.